# Swap multiple values a in single row

Tags: python, python-2.7, pandas

The column headers for my data frame are `Result`, `A1`, `B1`, `C1`, `A2`, `B2`, `C2`. I need to swap certain column values of my `DataFrame` based on a particular condition. Right now I am doing:

```
idx = (replaced['Result']==0)
replaced.loc[idx,['A1','A2']] = replaced.loc[idx,['A2','A1']].values
replaced.loc[idx,['B1','B2']] = replaced.loc[idx,['B2','B1']].values
replaced.loc[idx,['C1','C2']] = replaced.loc[idx,['C2','C1']].values
replaced.loc[idx,['D1','D2']] = replaced.loc[idx,['D2','D1']].values
```

Can I do this in a single line? Or is there any other way to shorten all these lines?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What's wrong with

```
replaced.loc[idx,['A1','A2', 'B1', 'B2', 'C1', 'C2', 'D1', 'D2']] = replaced.loc[idx,['A2','A1', 'B2', 'B1', 'C2', 'C1', 'D2', 'D1']].values
```

It almost looks like just renaming the columns could work, in which case you could use a list comprehension that just switches the numbers in the column names.

Comment: Yes, sorry, I did not try it like this. This seems to work.